# How can I access values from a textbox another dialog/form in qt?

Tags: c++, qt, textbox, qt-creator, multiplication

I'm trying to complete this multiplication as it works out a value I need.

```
int n1 = textboxWeight.text().toInt();
int n2 = 4;
labelForcePS.setText(QString::number(n1 * n2));
```

Unfortunately, 'textboxWeight' is on a different dialog/form to my labelForcePS. I would like the label to equal whatever value is entered in the textbox * 4. 
I'm struggling to access the value from the textboxWeight as it's not on the same form as the label. I've been trying to experiment with signals and slots, without much luck! I'm new:/

**Would you guys know how to complete the multiplication while accessing the value from the other dialog/form?**

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:

This is my code for the form where I want the multiplication to happen:

```
#include "analytics.h"
#include "ui_analytics.h"
#include "ui_profiles.h"
#include "profiles.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"

analytics::analytics(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::analytics)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

analytics::~analytics()
{
    delete ui;
}

void analytics::on_calculatebtn_clicked()
{
    int n1 = Ui::profiles.getTextboxText().toInt();
    int n2 = 4;
    ui->labelForcePS->setText(QString::number(n1 * n2));
}
    QString profiles::getTextboxText(){
        return ui->textboxWeight->text();
    }
```

This is the code for the form where 'textboxWeight' is located:

```
#include "ui_profiles.h"
#include <QComboBox>
profiles::profiles(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::profiles)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

profiles::~profiles()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your second form is a `QDialog`, the simplest way to get it done is using a method that acts like a bridge between these two forms.

In your dialog class (second form) add a method like this:

```
QString MyDialog::getTextboxText(){
    return ui->mytextbox->text();
}
```

And in your first class, whenever you'd like to compute the multiplication, you do something like this:

```
int n1 = myDialog.getTextboxText().toInt();
int n2 = 4;
labelForcePS.setText(QString::number(n1 * n2));
```

---

**Edit #1:** It seems that the `profiles` class acts like a dialog even though it's not subclassing `QDialog`. Please note that it's better to extend `QDialog` not `QWidget` to create a customized dialog. `QDialog`s internally inherit `QWidget` class, though.

Okay, let's head back to your question. You should add that interface method to your `profiles` class. Like this:

- profiles.cpp:

  ```
  QString profiles::getTextboxText(){
      return ui->mytextbox->text();
  }
  ```
- profiles.h: (somewhere within public area of the `profiles` class)

  ```
  QString getTextboxText();
  ```

The second problem is here at `on_calculatebtn_clicked` method. `Ui::profiles` refers to the class itself, but you should call this method on an *instance* of this class. Only *static* methods can be called on a class name itself, not regular methods.

By the way, as a convention your class names should begin with a uppercase letter not a lowercase one. i.e. `Profiles` not `profiles`.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply again Frogatto! So do both bits of code go into the form/dialog where I want to complete my multiplication?

Comment: Also, I'm getting lots of not declared in scope errors, this may be because I'm putting the code in the wrong place though! Where you have put 'MyDialog' would I put the name of my form, I called it 'form' in mainwindow.h?

Comment: @Joe Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35520414/edit) your question and post your codes there. I can't help you without them.

Comment: Edited. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: I have a label on my analytics page which I'm trying to output 4 * whatever value the user enters into textboxWeight (on the profiles page)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104033/discussion-between-joe-and-hi-im-frogatto).

Comment: Really sorry for the nooby questions but how would I call an instance of the class? Rather than what I've already done?

Comment: Both forms are showing, i'm just getting errors with the multiplication because it's 'expecting a primary-expression before '.' token'. I'm still stuck with the original problem:/ Trying to get the multiplication to work with the data entered in the textbox. @Hi I'm Frogatto

Comment: At the moment, due to incomplete information I have, can't help you further more. Could you please send me your whole project via email?

Comment: You should have received an email on your .live account